# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null error for image upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi friends i am getting this error in following code:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`   on line 11

The line 11 is:

```
fileDiv.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  $(fileInput).show().focus().click().hide();
  e.preventDefault();
},false)
```

This is input file:

```
<input type="file" class="imageUploadBtn" id="upload-image" name="fotograflar[]" multiple="multiple">
```

In this code error on line 5:

```
console.log(fileInput);
fileInput.addEventListener("change",function(e){
  var files = this.files
  showThumbnail(files)
},false)
```

What is that error? Anyone can help me in this regard ? I am using this code for image upload but this error will not allow me!!

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
    jQuery(function($){
    var fileDiv = document.getElementById("upload");
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-image");
    console.log(fileInput);
    fileInput.addEventListener("change",function(e){
      var files = this.files
      showThumbnail(files)
    },false)

    fileDiv.addEventListener("click",function(e){
      $(fileInput).show().focus().click().hide();
      e.preventDefault();
    },false)

    fileDiv.addEventListener("dragenter",function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    },false);

    fileDiv.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    },false);

    fileDiv.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();

      var dt = e.dataTransfer;
      var files = dt.files;

      showThumbnail(files)
    },false);

    function showThumbnail(files){
      for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        var file = files[i]
        var imageType = /image.*/
        if(!file.type.match(imageType)){
          console.log("Not an Image");
          continue;
        }

        var image = document.createElement("img");
        // image.classList.add("")
        var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
        image.file = file;
        thumbnail.appendChild(image)

        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = (function(aImg){
          return function(e){
            aImg.src = e.target.result;
          };
        }(image))
        var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        image.onload= function(){
          ctx.drawImage(image,100,100)
        }
      }
    }
              });
               });
```

Comment: Do you have element on the page with id upload ?

Comment: It means `fileInput` is `null`.  Why are you using `.addEventListener()` when using jQuery? With jQuery, you can pass a *list* of event names and assign that handler with just one function call.

Comment: @Alexander the id is in my question:  `id="upload-image"`

Comment: maybe there is no element that have `id=upload` tag.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico But the function working fine in `localhost`

Comment: We cannot say why it-s working on localhost. We can just tell to you that when you have that error it means that there are not any element with attribute `id=upload` in your page. What that mean in your context is impossible to guess. Take a look to the source in your html by your browser and look for that element: you cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is looking for and element with ID 'upload':

```
'var fileDiv = document.getElementById("upload");'
```

but the actual id is 'upload-image'

`<input type="file" class="imageUploadBtn" id="upload-image" name="fotograflar[]" multiple="multiple">`

Change your this line to:

```
var fileDiv = document.getElementById("upload-image");
```

If it is working on localhost, then try this:
1. open your page in chrome browser
2. hit F12
3. on console of developer tool, type document.getElementById("upload");
4. Whatever is the output just move your mouse cursor on that to see where is that element on UI 
5. Repeat same with non localhost environment and verify/debug where is the problem.

This is to simple a problem and I am sure if you fiddle with debugger you can solve it yourself easily.

Answer (score 1):

We should also check where are we calling the javascript file in header or in the end of the `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` returns null when it can't find the element you're looking for. Trying to call functions on null will throw an error like the above. It seems just from the above that you do not have element with the ID `upload`.

Comment: Then the non-localhost environment where you moved the code to doesn't have an element with that ID.